# Programmatically submit drupal ubercart order

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I want to post to a php page with a username, password, billing information, product id, and credit card information and do the following:

-login or create account using passed credentials
-add to cart product id (if I even have to do this, I think I can just build the order with it instead)
- checkout and process payment with billing and credit card info

I have tried three different approaches.  [Here is a paste](http://pastebin.com/jDzy9x9s) of my latest attempt.  When I post to this page I can see the completed order in my drupal admin panel, it shows up as Payment Received.  All the billing and credit card info appears in the order info, and the balance shows up at $0 (paid for).  As far as drupal is concerned it looks like the order was successful but the card is never charged.

http://pastebin.com/jDzy9x9s

Any help or pointers would be great. Been stuck on this for a few days now.